# Using a rails partial in a jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to insert a partial into a jquery dialog box. The dialog box is working but no partial..

Here is my code :

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_note").click(function(){
        $("#notes").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @note)) %>").dialog({title: 'Basic Dialog'})
    })
})
```

**my view**

```
<div class="title">
        <span>Historique :</span>
        <span id="add_note">Ajouter une note</span>
      </div>

      <div id="notes">
      </div>
```

**my partial**
in myview/_note.html.erb

```
<div class="note">
    <%= form_for(@add_note) do |f| %>
        <dl>
          <dt>Type de note</dt>
          <dd><%= f.collection_select :note_type_id, NoteType.find(:all), :id, :label, :allow_blank => "Type" %></dd>
        </dl>
         <dl>
          <dt>Titre :</dt>
          <dd><%= f.text_field :title %></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
          <dt>Description :</dt>
          <dd><%= f.text_field :description %></dd>
        </dl>
        <%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => @project_id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :organization_id, :value => @project.organization_id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :user_create_id, :value => current_user.id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :domain_id, :value => current_user.domain_id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :created_at %>

        <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

If you have a clue, it would be very helpful!
Thanks

Fabien

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `application.js` file is a place for static JavaScript.  It is not passed to ERB for processing on each request, so your `<%= code %>` is never run.  If you point your browser to `/javascripts/application.js` you'll see what I'm talking about.

Make sure you have a good handle on how requests are processed in Rails.  You may be missing some details here.  `application.js` is a static file that exists in the `/public/javascripts` directory, so it is served up directly by your web server; Rails doesn't even get touched when the browser fetches it.  It is just like when you create a new rails app and you have to erase the `/public/index.html` file before Rails can process your `map.root` in the routes.rb file.

You have a few different options:

[Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus) is an older Railscast episode, but it's seems close to what you are looking for.  It uses a controller named `javascripts_controller` for generating dynamic javascripts.  This is not a very fine grained approach.

In [this episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2), the method Ryan uses for adding fields for a nested model can be adapted to fit your needs.  I have used this method a few times and it works very well.

### Recommended Method

You can also call an action that returns the html of the partial via ajax and use the result to `$(#notes).html(result)`.  A quick search on `rails jquery ajax` offers a few guides on how to implement this ([Here](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/02/24/jquery-rails-and-ajax) is one that seems reasonable).  [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery) is another Railscast episode that deals with jQuery and Rails 2.  I wouldn't recommend using jRails at this point because it's fairly outdated, and as the episode mentions, it kind of defeats the purpose of switching to jQuery as the Rails 2 helpers generate obtrusive JavaScript.

This is a flexible way of doing things.  You have a generic set of static JavaScript used to call remote methods.  In individual controller methods, you can [respond_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) these ajax calls and return JavaScript with dynamic data, html, or JSON.

The methods in jQuery to look at for ajax are listed in [this section](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) of the jQuery api.  `$.ajax` `$.post` and `$.get` are the main ones.

For your example, the `$.get` would be a good place to start.  Here is an example right from the api docs:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

[Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) is a Railscast on how Rails 3 handles unobtrusive JavaScript along with HTML5 custom attributes.  You can mimic this approach in Rails 2, but the standard helper methods wont generate the `data-remote`, `data-method`, `data-disable-with`, or other `data-*` attributes for you.  You can see in the [jQuery version](http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js) of the Rails 3 ujs, that it is most like the previous method I mentioned where controller methods are called with `$.ajax` and handle the response differently depending on the dataType (which is 'script' by default.

Comment: @Fabien: You're welcome.  I updated my answer with some more information including the Rails 3 way of doing things.  I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I too have been trying to do this and stumbled upon this solution:

http://jenwendling.com/quick-clean-modal-form-dialogs-w-jquery-eeeee/

might be easier to implement

Answer (score 2):

After I look at Rails casts and documentation, I do best by following that up with looking at real world examples and tweaking that to what I need.  So if you do go the Ajax route (what Awgy suggested) and want more examples, then here's a link in addition to InfectiouSoul's link (from the same site), this one showing an example of a dialog using an ajax request.

http://jenwendling.com/fancy-forgot-password-with-jqueryui-and-rails/